# Why does cloud foundry download all buildpacks?

Tags: cloud-foundry

When I deploy a Cloud Foundry app, it installs the buildpacks for ruby, php, javascript, python, java, go, and more.

Why does it do this? My project only uses Java, so I assume Cloud Foundry downloads all the buildpacks for any project, regardless of the files being deployed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At that point Cloud Foundry doesn't know which buildpack to use and to figure this out, it needs to download all of them. To specify which buildpack you would like to use, add the `-b` switch to your `cf push` commmand. `cf push <app name> -b java_buildpack`

Comment: You can also specify the buildpack in your manifest file using the buildpack property.

Example: buildpack: java_buildpack

Link with more information https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#buildpack

Comment: `cf buildpacks` to list all buildpacks